# What is this word being said "bale" not sure of spelling" in a video?

Tags: expresiones

In this video, at about the 40 second mark, at about the 40second mark 
Did she say "dale", or "bale"?
https://youtu.be/-i5Dlh7hatY?list=PL6Hvozbgsbx6xgxHBY35bHHEEn7hYpa44&t=38

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: Fyi, dale and vale (mostly used in Spain)  both  mean the same thing: OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She said "Vale", in English, that word is similar to `Ok`.

example:

```
 -ok, let's move on-
 "-Vale, sigamos adelante-"
```